# error when creating an array: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel-6.2

I was creating an array using labels and creating arrays inside arrays, when Laravel 6.2 gave me this error:

Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

It's not syntax error.

```
[
'product_id'=>(string)$productId,
'name'=>
'SubscriptionPlan',
'description'=>
'SubscriptionPlan',
'status'=>'ACTIVE',
'billing_cycles'=>[
0=>[
'frequency'=>[
'interval_unit'=>'MONTH',
'interval_count'=>1,
],
'tenure_type'=>'REGULAR',
'sequence'=>2,
'total_cycles'=>999,
'pricing_scheme'=>[
'fixed_price'=>[
'value'=>(string)$p->monthlyFee,
'currency_code'=>'USD',
],
],
],
],
'payment_preferences'=>[
'auto_bill_outstanding'=>true,
'setup_fee'=>[
'value'=>'0',
'currency_code'=>'USD',
],
'setup_fee_failure_action'=>'CONTINUE',
'payment_failure_threshold'=>3,
],
'taxes'=>[
'percentage'=>'10',
'inclusive'=>false,
],
];
```

Comment: Can you provide the piece of code producing the error please ?

Comment: the code is too long, so I coudn't add to comments here

Comment: You should edit your original post and paste the code between code tag.
The code is hard to read but my guess is that ```$p->monthlyFee``` is an object... So you can't make it a string this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're casting two variable to string:

- $productId
- $p->monthlyFee

One of them is an object.
You can't cast object to string this way.
You should try to dump both variables to see which one is the cause of the problem.

Happy new year !

Comment: Thank you, it was the $productId

Comment: Can you flag it as resolved please ?